# SQL query to get the "latest" value for each location

Tags: sql, informix

What I thought would be a simple thing to solve has now bugged for quite some time. Now I need help from you guys.

In Informix I have a table "temperatures" like this:

```
locId    dtg               temp
100      2009-02-25 10:00  15
200      2009-02-25 10:00  20
300      2009-02-25 10:00  24
100      2009-02-25 09:45  13
300      2009-02-25 09:45  16
200      2009-02-25 09:45  18
400      2009-02-25 09:45  12
100      2009-02-25 09:30  11
300      2009-02-25 09:30  14
200      2009-02-25 09:30  15
400      2009-02-25 09:30  10
```

I am trying to get the latest temp for each locId that has updated values within the last 20 min.

So the result I want from the table above would be (say I run the query at 2009-02-25 10:10):

```
locId    dtg               temp
100      2009-02-25 10:00  15
200      2009-02-25 10:00  20
300      2009-02-25 10:00  24
```

One more thing that complicates things is that I would like to be able to supply a list on locId that should be selected. I mean use something like "...locId IN (100,200,400)..."

I have tried to use a join on a sub query (as suggested in [SQL Query to get latest price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404/sql-query-to-get-latest-price) ) but I can´t get it to work. Not even without the extra "update within the last 20 min".

```
select t.*
from temperatures as t
 JOIN (select locId, max(dtg) from temperatures where locId IN (100,200,400)  group by locId) as l 
    on l.locId=t.locId and l.dtg=t.dtg
where locId in (100,200,400)
```

This query gives me SQL error but I cant find error. 
Is there an error I can´t find or is this way to do it not possible in Informix.

Or is there some other way to go? All help appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what it means that you "can't find the error?"  Do you mean there is no error message, or that you don't know the cause of the error message?  May we see the exact error message?

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL errors can be corrected using the following syntax:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM temperatures AS t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT locId, MAX(dtg) AS maxdtg 
    FROM temperatures 
    WHERE locId IN (100,200,400)  GROUP BY locId
) AS l 
ON l.locId = t.locId AND maxdtg = t.dtg
WHERE t.locId IN (100,200,400)
```

EDIT: Also, one proper and more dynamic way to go about this:

```
SELECT t2.* FROM (
    SELECT locId, MAX(dtg) AS maxdtg 
    FROM temperatures 
    GROUP BY locId
) t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT locId, dtg, temp 
    FROM temperatures
) t2 
ON t2.locId = t1.locId 
    AND t2.dtg = t1.maxdtg
WHERE t2.dtg > CURRENT YEAR TO MINUTE - 20 UNITS MINUTE
```

EDIT: Was looking for posts more than 20 minutes in the future instead of 20 minutes old... oops!

EDIT AGAIN: Forgot this was for Informix database... gave MSSQL syntax for where clause.

Comment: DATEADD() is not standard in Informix or the SQL standard; nor is getdate().  The equivalent expression is 'CURRENT YEAR TO MINUTE - 20 UNITS MINUTE'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to name the max(dtg) column in the subselect - your query just matches all rows by time not just the latest.

```
select t1.locId, t1.temp, time
   from temperatures t1
      inner join ( select t1.locId, t1.temp, max(t1.dtg) as time
                     from temperatures group by t1.locId, t1.temp) as t2
        on t1.locId = t2.locId
           and t1.dtg = t2.time
    where t1.locId in (100,200,400)
```

You can add the where condition inside the sub select as well and also you could add a condition to get only the readings in the last 20 minutes.

edit: as per comment - I had typed the wrong join and other errors.

---

Some assistance - the references to t1 in the sub-query are wrong.  You need an extra table reference (t3):

```
select t1.locId, t1.temp, time
   from temperatures t1
        inner join (select t3.locId, t3.temp, max(t3.dtg) as time
                      from temperatures as t3 group by t3.locId, t3.temp) as t2
                        on t1.locId = t2.locId and t1.dtg = t2.time
    where t1.locId in (100,200,400)
```

This yields the result:

```
100    15    2009-02-25 10:00
200    20    2009-02-25 10:00
100    13    2009-02-25 09:45
200    18    2009-02-25 09:45
400    12    2009-02-25 09:45
100    11    2009-02-25 09:30
200    15    2009-02-25 09:30
400    10    2009-02-25 09:30
```

Unfortunately, this is not the required result, though it is getting closer.  Part of the trouble is that you don't want t3.temp in the sub-select or its GROUP BY clause.

Comment: The join should be on the `locid` and `t2.time`

Comment: Also, ambiguous column name `locId` on line 5.

Comment: md5sum I agree makes it clearer - however I think the temperatures in the subselect is hidden

Comment: @Mark - Tested, failed:

Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Ambiguous column name 'locId'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Ambiguous column name 'locId'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Ambiguous column name 'locId'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'locId'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'temp'.

Comment: @Mark - Apparently `temp` is also ambiguous between `t1` and `t2`.

Comment: LoL... I do that quite often myself :D

Answer (score 0):

I chose to create a one-row table 'RefDateTime' to hold the reference time (2009-02-25 10:10).  There are other ways to handle that - notably writing `DATETIME(2009-02-25 10:10) YEAR TO MINUTE.

```
CREATE TABLE temperatures
(
    locId   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    dtg     DATETIME YEAR TO MINUTE NOT NULL,
    temp    INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Temperatures VALUES(100, '2009-02-25 10:00', 15);
INSERT INTO Temperatures VALUES(200, '2009-02-25 10:00', 20);
INSERT INTO Temperatures VALUES(300, '2009-02-25 10:00', 24);
INSERT INTO Temperatures VALUES(100, '2009-02-25 09:45', 13);
INSERT INTO Temperatures VALUES(300, '2009-02-25 09:45', 16);
INSERT INTO Temperatures VALUES(200, '2009-02-25 09:45', 18);
INSERT INTO Temperatures VALUES(400, '2009-02-25 09:45', 12);
INSERT INTO Temperatures VALUES(100, '2009-02-25 09:30', 11);
INSERT INTO Temperatures VALUES(300, '2009-02-25 09:30', 14);
INSERT INTO Temperatures VALUES(200, '2009-02-25 09:30', 15);
INSERT INTO Temperatures VALUES(400, '2009-02-25 09:30', 10);

CREATE TABLE RefDateTime
(
    reftime DATETIME YEAR TO MINUTE NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO RefDateTime VALUES('2009-02-25 10:10');

SELECT t1.locID, t1.dtg, t1.temp
  FROM temperatures AS t1 JOIN
    (SELECT t2.locID, MAX(t2.dtg) AS latest
        FROM temperatures AS t2
       WHERE t2.dtg > (SELECT RefTime - 20 UNITS MINUTE FROM RefDateTime)
         AND t2.locID IN (100, 200, 400)
       GROUP BY t2.locID) AS t3 ON t1.locID = t3.locID AND t1.dtg = t3.latest
;
```

This gives what I believe is the correct result:

```
100     2009-02-25 10:00      15
200     2009-02-25 10:00      20
```

When the 't2.locID IN (100, 200, 400)' condition is omitted, it also shows the row with the locID of 300 (and temperature of 24).