# Return newest results from DB

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of answers recorded over time, but I only want to return the newest version of each answer.

eg.

```
1, Bob
2, Bob
3, Rita
4, Sue
5, Bob
6, Sue
```

...Should return:

```
3, Rita
5, Bob
6, Sue
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Lots of ideas, how about yours?

Comment: Why do I need a data_updated column? The index is sufficient.

Comment: to know the date of the last inserted,If you didn't set a time you wont be 100% sure about the last value or  You can use a auto-increment and when you display the result set an `order by id desc`. I'd preffer the timestamp

Comment: In my opinion, relying on the unique key increasing as a sign of its recency isn't best practice. True, it will work, but a `created_at` is guaranteed to provide results in the correct order.

Comment: The index is auto-incremented so there's no need for a created date.

Comment: Why you have duplicate records? What you are actually doing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query to get latest price](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404/sql-query-to-get-latest-price)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, name is the column with the names, id the column with the numbers:

```
SELECT MAX(ID), Name  
FROM Table  
GROUP By Name
```

***EDIT:***
If you additionally want to order your query by ID, try the following:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) as ID, Name  
FROM Table  
GROUP By Name
ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `SELECT DISTINCT col [...]`.
It should work!

Edit : or `SELECT [...] GROUP BY col`

Comment: you would also get all columns if you want to select more than one column and instead there are columns missing...

Comment: Yes, group by is better thats why I edit...

Comment: But by grouping, or using distinct, I will have no control on the whether the result returned is ASC or DESC.

Comment: the first just don't work, has nothing to do if your second answer is better, and even your edit won't solve the problem, it not even works properly.